# Multiple results from criteria in single cell

Tags: vba, excel

So I have been going at this for awhile now and I am either just missing something or just dumb. Essentially I am trying to do something similar to the countifs function in Excel where you can use multiple criteria but instead of returning a count I am looking to return the matched cell values in a single cell.

I have named ranges for all three fields that is used to pull into the results for the numbers but now I am looking for a way to grab each case and notes and put them into the perspective cell as shown in the last image. I dont mind using VBA to achieve this or even formulas if possible I have just gone through everything and just cant figure this one out.

[image: Data]

This is essentially what I am trying to achieve.
[image: Results]

Comment: Forgot to mention should be compatible with Outlook 2013 as well.

Comment: *I dont mind using VBA to achieve this * - you will need VBA to achieve this, and i order to get VBA help here, you'll need to show the efforts you made to accomplish your task and where it's failing. SO will not write the code for you, especially something as complex as this.

Comment: My apologies I thought i had submitted the code that I had with it, I will get it in when I return back to my computer. Been awhile since I have used the site so formatting got a bit confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim dict1 As Object, dictApp As Object, dictNotApp As Object
    Dim c1 As Variant, k As Variant, j As Variant
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, rowCount As Long
    Dim rngName As Range, rngCase As Range, rngNotes As Range, rngFound As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String, strApp As String, strNotApp As String, strNotes As String
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet, outputSheet As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'set you worksheets here
    Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set outputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictApp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictNotApp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'get last row with data
    lastRow = dataSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'you can replace following ranges to your named ranges
    Set rngName = dataSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    Set rngCase = dataSheet.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
    Set rngNotes = dataSheet.Range("C2:C" & lastRow)

    'put unique names to dict1
    c1 = dataSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    For i = 1 To UBound(c1, 1)
        dict1(c1(i, 1)) = 1
    Next i

    rowCount = 2 'this is the starting row no for ouputSheet, row 1 being the header
    For Each k In dict1.keys
        strApp = ""
        strNotApp = ""
        strNotes = ""

        'for each unique name get the values of case and notes
        Set rngFound = dataSheet.Columns(1).Find(What:=k, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = rngFound.Address
            Do
                If rngFound.Offset(0, 2) = "Approved" Then
                    'if value of notes is approved put data in dictApp
                    dictApp.Add rngFound.Offset(0, 1), rngFound.Offset(0, 2)
                Else
                    'if value of notes is not approved put data in dictNotApp
                    dictNotApp.Add rngFound.Offset(0, 1), rngFound.Offset(0, 2)
                End If

                Set rngFound = rngName.FindNext(rngFound)
            Loop While Not rngFound Is Nothing And rngFound.Address <> FirstAddress

            'create case string for approved notes
            For Each j In dictApp.keys
                If strApp = "" Then
                    strApp = j
                Else
                    strApp = strApp & vbCrLf & j
                End If
            Next
            'create case and notes string for notes not approved
            For Each j In dictNotApp.keys
                If strNotApp = "" Then
                    strNotApp = j
                    strNotes = dictNotApp(j)
                Else
                    strNotApp = strNotApp & vbCrLf & j
                    strNotes = strNotes & vbCrLf & dictNotApp(j)
                End If
            Next
        End If

        'display values in outputSheet
        outputSheet.Cells(rowCount, 1) = k
        outputSheet.Cells(rowCount, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngName, k)
        outputSheet.Cells(rowCount, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rngName, k, rngNotes, "<>Approved")
        outputSheet.Cells(rowCount, 4) = strApp
        outputSheet.Cells(rowCount, 5) = strNotApp
        outputSheet.Cells(rowCount, 6) = strNotes

        dictApp.RemoveAll
        dictNotApp.RemoveAll
        rowCount = rowCount + 1
    Next k
    'center align the data
    With outputSheet.UsedRange
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

See image for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are just trying to summarize data.  If so, a PivotTable will be your easiest and best option - plus there is no VBA code or formula writing!  I added in one extra column for counting purposes and created two separate PivotTables.  Below is an example of what I put together... hope this helps!
[image]

Comment: I thought about using a pivot table as well and still may if it would be easier thanks for the answer